# Adding link message in a SOAP instruction

Tags: javascript, soap, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am actually writing a SOAP command *(from javascript)* for an **Outlook Add-In** that sends a mail *(to run on an Exchange Server)*. In the mail, I want to include 2 hyperlinks in 2 different lines. As of now, the code is as follows;

```
{ 

                var soapNotificationItem = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
                    '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
                    '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
                    '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
                    '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
                    '  <soap:Header>' +
                    '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
                    '  </soap:Header>' +
                    '  <soap:Body>' + 
                    '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">' +
                    '      <m:Items>' + 
                    '<t:Message>'+
                    '<t:Subject>Notification email</t:Subject>'+
                    '<t:Body BodyType="HTML">' + MyMessage + '</t:Body>' +
                    ' <t:ExtendedProperty>' +
                    ' <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="16367" PropertyType="SystemTime" />'+
                    '<t:Value>2014-01-02T21:09:52.000</t:Value>'+
                    '</t:ExtendedProperty>'+
                    '<t:ToRecipients>' + MyMailAdd + '</t:ToRecipients>' +
                    '</t:Message>'+

                    '      </m:Items>' +
                    '    </m:CreateItem>' +
                    '  </soap:Body>' +
                    '</soap:Envelope>';
                mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapNotificationItem, soapNotificationItemCallback);
            }
```

As you can see, I have my parameter `MyMessage`, which I am constructing separately, as represented in the below example;

```
MyMessage = "www.mylink1.com" + "&#10;" + "www.mylink2.com"
```

Any Idea how I make hyperlinks out of the 2 links with a line break in between. The `&#10;` does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to find a solution to the issue. By specifying the Body type to HTML `<t:Body BodyType="HTML">`, I have been able to add simple HTML.

To simplify, the HTML construction follows the below format, though in my case, I was reading the data from a XML file, looping and concatenating the message to be displayed.

```
var link1 = "www.test.com"
var MyMessage = "<strong>Click on link :</strong>: <a href=\"#" + link1  + "\">" + Link1 + "</a>";
```

Then coming to the **SOAP** part, it remains as is;
    {

```
            var soapNotificationItem = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
                '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
                '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
                '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
                '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
                '  <soap:Header>' +
                '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
                '  </soap:Header>' +
                '  <soap:Body>' + 
                '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">' +
                '      <m:Items>' + 
                '<t:Message>'+
                '<t:Subject>Notification email</t:Subject>'+
                '<t:Body BodyType="HTML">' + MyMessage + '</t:Body>' +
                ' <t:ExtendedProperty>' +
                ' <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="16367" PropertyType="SystemTime" />'+
                '<t:Value>2014-01-02T21:09:52.000</t:Value>'+
                '</t:ExtendedProperty>'+
                '<t:ToRecipients>' + MyMailAdd + '</t:ToRecipients>' +
                '</t:Message>'+

                '      </m:Items>' +
                '    </m:CreateItem>' +
                '  </soap:Body>' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
            mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapNotificationItem, soapNotificationItemCallback);
        }
```

NOTE: for the link to appear correctly in Office365, do add the `#` in front of the link.